# sparse-checkout to clone a specific sub-folder on the root of the repository

Tags: git

I have a git repo that has a submodule inside it. "*main_repo/submodule*"

I don't want to see all files and folders of this submodule, that is why I am using `sparse-checkout` in this submodule to get only the folder I am interested in:

```
# Here I am executing in my submodule folder.
git sparse-checkout init --no-cone
git sparse-checkout set /project/src/unit
```

This mounts the whole directory tree in my submodule like this
"*main_repo/submodule/project/src/unit*"

Is it somehow possible to access the "***unit***" folder directly as the root of the submodule? So I can access its content directly through: "***main_repo/submodule/<files_and_folders_inside_unit>***"?

I am aware that I can clone the repo in a hidden sub-folder somewhere in my repo, and then create a symlink to the folder I want, but I am looking for a better and cleaner solution if possible.